# Irreducible in $(\mathbb{Z}[i])[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Prove that $p(x)=x^3-6x^2+4ix+1+3i$ is irreducible in $(\mathbb{Z}[i])[x]$.

I'm not so clear on irreducibility in specific instances like this one. I know I need to show that if $p(x)=q(x)r(x)$ then W.L.O.G. $q(x)$ is a unit. Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is an integral domain, it follows that $(\mathbb{Z}[i])[x]$ is also an integral domain, so the units are simply $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$. Some back and forth feedback would be preferred to a straightaway proof.

I know that $\deg(p(x))=3$ $\Rightarrow \deg(q(x))+\deg(r(x))=3$. The question becomes how to show $\deg(q(x))=0$.

Comment: Hint: $1+3i=(1+i)(2+i)$ and $2i=(1+i)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a third degree plynomial is not irreducible, there has to be a first degree divisor. So if $x^3-6x^2-4ix+1+3i$ is not irreducible, it has a root in $\Bbb Z[i]$ and this root must divide $1+3i$. So you only have to check among the divisors of $1+3i$.

Comment: This implicitly uses the Rational Root Test, i.e. $\,\Bbb Z[i]\,$ is integrally closed, being a UFD. Invoking Eisenstein is easier, using the prime factor $\,p = 1+i\,$ of $\,2.\ \ $

Comment: The method that Bill is suggesting involves theory that my course has not (and will not) cover. The divisors of $1+3i$ are $1+i$ and $2+i$, which are both of the form $a+bi\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Is this what you are saying?

Comment: This is doable but there are a bunch of divisors of $1+3i$, including $1-i$, $1+2i$, $1-2i$...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $ $ If $\,p = \pi\bar \pi$ divides all non-extremal coefs of $\,f(x)\,$ and $\,p\,||\,N(f(0))$ then the [Eisenstein irreducibility test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) applies for prime $\,\pi\,$ or $\,\bar \pi,\,$ since e.g. $\,\pi^2\!\mid f(0)\,\Rightarrow\,p^2\! =N(\pi^2)\mid N(f(0)).$

Answer (score 3):

I like the solutions by others, but if you want something different, then you can use the fact that $\Bbb{Z}[i]/\langle 4+i\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z}_{17}$. Reducing the coefficients of your polynomial modulo $\frak{p}=4+i$ (basically replacing $i$ with $-4$ and reducing rational integers modulo $17$) gives the polynomial
$$
x^3-6x^2-16x-11=x^3-6x^2+x+6\in\Bbb{Z}_{17}[x].
$$
Have fun checking that this has no zeros in $\Bbb{Z}_{17}$, and is thus irreducible in
$\Bbb{Z}_{17}[x]$, and consequently also in $\Bbb{Z}[i][x].$

Comment: Very pleasing!!

Answer (score 2):

Another method, like @BillDubuque’s:

The sextic $f\overline f$ is equal to $x^6 - 12x^5 + 36x^4 + 2x^3 + 4x^2 + 24x + 10$, a $\mathbb Z$-irreducible polynomial. Oughtn’t a nontrivial $\mathbb Z[i]$-factoring of the original $f$ induce a factoring of $f\overline f\,$?